# iPhone webapp dimensions

Tags: iphone, css, web-applications, resolution

getting really confused here now after googling for the last 40 mins. I need a definite answer.

Im making a webapp for ipod touch, iphone(all gens) it i will be run in full screen mode as a native app eventually.

however what i want to know is. what width: and height: do i set my wrapper to in the css.... i need the dimentions, i get 960wide, 320wide 640wide i get all confused, i just need a definite answer of how many pixels wide it should be and high in portrait mode.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dimen`s`ions should be

`Width: 320 x Height: 480`

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set your wrapper width to 320px for portrait mode, although the user will have the option to view the web app in landscape mode so if you can get away with using percentages (i.e. `wrapper {width:100%}`) you'll be better off.

Comment: thanks, 320px has been working fine, i've disabled landscape mode anyway through xcode so that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not set it as a percentage and have it always fill the screen no matter the device used .. iPad, iPhone# etc.

For example:

```
.container {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0 3%; /* Give it some space from the sides. */
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Something along those lines?

Comment: i thought about this, but i've got absolute positioned elements so not sure how they would handle? plus its iphone only so dont need this functionality, thanks though